# What is the ideal size of a module of Angular 11?

Tags: angular, angular11

Imagine that you are develop a new modular app in angular and need to determinate when create a new module.

If the pages are no common components is a best practice do a module per page?

**Are any ideal size in the Angular modules? Or a min o max to improve the velocity?**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

That's a debatable question. but by default 2mb-s is the recommended max for the **app**. You should get warnings if your go over 2mb of **app** size. Your question asks about module not app. There is no ideal size for the module. The smaller the module the better. You should try to split up modules by logic, not by size.